# JQuery click on element name

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following bootstrap button group:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input name="act_con" value="No" checked="" booking_id="22" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="act_con" value="Tel" booking_id="22" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="act_con" value="Email" booking_id="22" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

I want to make something happen when a button is clicked, so am trying the following:

```
$('input[name="act_con"]').click(function(){
    alert('hey');
});
```

However this only works on the first button, I'm guessing because three buttons with same name but they need to be because radio buttons.

Does this only work with indivually named elements?

I also tried adding a class to the inputs and changing the JQ to click on the class but that didn't work either

Is there a way to make this work so I can make something happen when any button is clicked?

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FxZ6G/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't alert anything for me; Chrome 35 on OSX. Change the selector to `label` and it works, although you haven't described your goal, so I'm not sure if it matches what you need.

Comment: You need yo click on the input, that has a minimal size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to target the `closest label` to bind event, since the `radio` button is wrapped with it,

```
$('input[name="act_con"]').closest('label.btn').click(function () {
    alert('hey');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FxZ6G/2/)

Comment: I was going to write the same. Or maybe another solution that makes input same size label.

Comment: Ah ok, is that because it's the label element thats taking the click because it surrounds the input?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You are clicking on button image and it is label element in your code, so bind click event to lable. Here label has `class="btn"`.

And it is good to call jquery inside `$(function(){ ...` which ensure that it will execute after DOM prepared.

```
$(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
    alert('hey');
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FxZ6G/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use following as actually label is getting clicked :
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FxZ6G/6/)

```
$('input[name="act_con"]').parent('label').click(function () {
    alert('hey');
});
```

Here , look for parent  `label`  ,and then fire if its getting clicked.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Are you using bootstrap? I noticed the font-awesome icons that often go with bootstrap. If so, the styles will set your input to a z-index lower than the labels and they will not receive the click events.

I've added your code to a jsfiddle and it looks like your click handler works just fine. You should try checking your error logs as there may be other issues. Or perhaps your browser is configured to ignore duplicate alert messages. If you've ever seen a popup come up and checked the check box, it will do so (please refer to the following image)
[image: alert popup offering message blocking]

Something else that you should also consider is using event delegation instead of attaching a click handler to each input. This is more performant, generally a better practice in javascript and quite easy to do in jQuery. The updated code would look like the following:

```
$(function() {
  $('.btn-group').on('click', 'input[name="act_con"]',function(){
    alert('hey');
  });
});
```

**EDIT** Also wrap dom dependent code in jquery on dom ready handler to avoid issues with selecting on elements that may not be loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('label.btn ').click(function () {
   alert( $(this).find("[type=radio]").val());
   //it will return "no" or "tel","email"
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FxZ6G/7/)